# API fica em Branco quando é Atualizada

Tags: angular

Estou fazendo um crud usando Angular e estou com problemas para atualizar os valores dos meus objetos da API.
Basicamente, quando executo o método de atualizar ele atualiza na API, mas o campo que foi atualizado, ao invés de receber o conteúdo atualizado se atualiza embranco, como se fosse uma string vazia.
Fiz um debuger e estou recebendo o valor do campo que quero retornar dentro da minha variável e passo esse valor como parâmetro dentro do meu método.
Preciso saber o que está errado e como devo corrigir. Obrigado!

**Serviço usado no método:**

```
    atualizaProdutos(id: number, produto: Produtos): Observable<Produtos>{
    const url = `${environment.produtosApiUrl}/produtos/${id}`;
    return this.http.put<Produtos>(url, produto.descricao);
  }
```

**Método:**

```
atualizaProduto(id: number, descricao){
    console.log(descricao);
    this.produtosServices.atualizaProdutos(id, descricao)
    .subscribe(() => {alert('Descrição Atualizada!')},
    () => {alert('Falha ao Editar a Descrição!')});
    debugger
  }
```

**Botão:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="atualizaProduto(id, descricao)">Salvar Edição</button>
```

Comment: Não ficou clara sua pergunta, onde deixa o campo em branco, no banco? Se for no banco o problema não é no front e sim na api.

Comment: Após clicar no botão, quando recarrego a página para ver a lista, o campo que antes tinha algo aparece em branco. Exemplo, antes tinha descrição: hamburguer   depois que atualizo o campo fica em branco.

Comment: Vc tem um método POST que faz a inserção no banco de dados, mas, aí vc tem que ter um método GET par quando a página for carregado ir no banco e trazer os dados no campo.

Comment: Sim, mas ai ele só iria atualizar o conteúdo que existe na API. O problema é que quando eu atualizo, o conteúdo que vai para a API não vai e o campo descricao do objeto fica como se fosse uma string vazia e ai quando eu atualizo a página o objeto aparece, mas com o campo descricao vazio. Ele não insere o conteúdo atualizado na API.